# Chrome datepicker bug

Tags: jquery, laravel, google-chrome

I've built my own CMS using Laravel and Jquery. And in there I just leave the field as type date and let chrome set its own datepicker.

[image]

```
<input type="date" id="show-date-start" name="show-date-start" aria-errormessage="show-date-start-error" value="{{$show[0]->start_date}}" required>
```

The problem is that if I manually edit the year for the start date, it will appear correctly when I enter it in (say 2016), but when the data gets submitted the Request object shows that the year was set as 2014. I've tested different dates but, intermittently, the submitted year is behind by 2 years (i enter 2015 but it is submitted at 2013, 2012 is submitted as 2010). This happens 2 submits in a row, or every other one. Though sometimes the year is saved correctly. What could this be?

The problem exists as soon as the submit request occurs. Here's my code:

```
  /**
   * Store the edits
   */
  public function store_show_info(Request $request){

    $input = $request->all();

    dd($input); 

    ....
```

All I'm doing is submitting the form, grabbing the request object, and (for testing purposed) just dump dying the results. **Could this be an issue with Laravel 5.7.14, or is there a bug in the Chrome date picker?** Or is the issue that I'm loading Jquery as a library and there is some conflict? By the way I've tested this in firefox and it works with every request. So it possibly could just be a bug in Chrome.

Thoughts? I'm stumped here.

Comment: What is the format of $show[0]->start_date ? I'd print it next to the field also... just to compare if you r getting the same or two different values. The date value format should be in YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: The format was in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss(the standard sql query statement. But it's a timestamp and not a date) Perhaps the timestamp is throwing it off. I'll check it out.

Comment: It was a great idea Nawed, but I checked and the format was correct. The value from the DB was put in that field as "2020-03-02". But the issue is that when I change that date. So is there some unknown bug that I've found in Chrome? Perhaps I need to set up a vanilla php test site, and debug the heck out of that date picker. 

Worst case scenario I can always turn off the default Chrome date picker, and install an jquery picker instead. 

Still though, I'm stumped. Not sure how the value of a date can be changed from the time submit is clicked and I access the post array.

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Comment: I honestly think there is just a rare bug in the chrome date picker. If you manually enter values in certain ways, then it changes the value that is sent via the post array. This shouldn't be an issue with Laravel since it's just the post array, but I think there is an issue on the JS end for the date picker. But if you just use the mouse it's fine.